# how to check if an element is present in an array or not in javascript without using for loop or any method of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to check if an element is present in an array or not in JavaScript without using `for` loop or any method of array like `map`, `reduce`?
`let numList= [1,2,3,6,9,2,-8,20];` I want to check for 9 and 30, if it exists or not without using `for` loop or any array method

Comment: If you have some kind of restriction, can you explain why? Why can't you use a loop or any built-in method?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli was an interview question :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose one option would be to convert the array to a `Set` and check `Set.has`:

```js
let numList= [1,2,3,6,9,2,-8,20];
const set = new Set(numList);
console.log(set.has(9));
console.log(set.has(30));
```

Checking whether a `Set` has an element has complexity of `O(1)`, which is lower complexity than any of the array methods or `for` loops, which are `O(N)` or `O(log N)`, so when you have a very large array and you want to check whether it has certain elements, converting it to a `Set` first can be a good idea.

Comment: Constructing the `Set` is of course at least linear time; it helps only if you need to make multiple queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the array to string using JSON.stringify and use [**String includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check if the string contains the specific searched value

```js
let numList = [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 2, -8, 20];
let m = JSON.stringify(numList)
console.log(m.includes(-8))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a while loop you may be able to implement a binary search. Since it was for an interview question I wouldn't be surprised if this is along the lines of what they were looking for.

Here is the traditional algorithm in psuedocode, borrowed from [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search)

```
BinarySearch(A[0..N-1], value) {
  low = 0
  high = N - 1
  while (low <= high) {
      // invariants: value > A[i] for all i < low
                     value < A[i] for all i > high
      mid = (low + high) / 2
      if (A[mid] > value)
          high = mid - 1
      else if (A[mid] < value)
          low = mid + 1
      else
          return mid
  }
  return not_found // value would be inserted at index "low"
}
```

Comment: I think it;s probably likely that if a for loop is excluded, a while loop would be as well.